# Scheme Lists of Functions - How to access a function in the list?

Tags: scheme

In scheme, how can I access a certain function inside of a list and pass a variable to that function?

```
(define f 
        '((lambda (n) (+ n 2)) 
          (lambda (n) (* n 2)) 
          (lambda (n) (* n n))))
```

I have defined this list f which has in it 3 different functions and I want to know what I can type into scheme to be able to say pass 3 to the second function in the list?

I thought that something like `((cadr f) 3)` would work but I can't seem to figure it out, any help would be appreciated I'm really new to Scheme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have here isn't a list of function but a list of list of symbols. Containing also some symbols... Since you quoted everything, then everything is quoted and only numbers and lists, strings are self-quoted. If you want to keep objects inside a list, you have two choices here:

Create a list instead of quoting it.

```
(define f 
        (list (lambda (n) (+ n 2)) 
              (lambda (n) (* n 2)) 
              (lambda (n) (* n n))))
```

Pseudo-quote it and unquote each function declaration

```
(define f 
        `(,(lambda (n) (+ n 2)) 
          ,(lambda (n) (* n 2)) 
          ,(lambda (n) (* n n))))
```

To be honest, the explicit list seems a bit nicer than the pseudo-quote version.

What your quoted version gives you is this:

```
(define f 
        (list (list 'lambda (list 'n) (list '+ 'n 2)) 
              (list 'lambda (list 'n) (list '* 'n 2)) 
              (list 'lambda (list 'n) (list '* 'n 'n))))
```

Quote isn't a shorthand for makings lists. It's a shorthand to not evaluate anything.

Comment: I thought that (lambda (arg) (expr)) was the format for anonymous function definition?

Comment: It is, but since you quoted it, you end up with a list of symbols. like this: `(list 'lambda (list 'arg) (list 'expr))`

Comment: @KaileeKerr Scheme evaluates from left to right, when it sees a quote, it doesn't evaluate anything. Quote isn't a shorthand for makings lists. It's a shorthand to not evaluate anything.

Comment: Okay I see now! Thank you very much! I was now able to evaluate using > ((cadr f) 3) using the first method you showed to create a list

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix The "Quote isn't a shorthand..." bit is a great description. Maybe you should add it to the answer so everyone sees it. I think quoting is a common stumbling block for beginners (I know it was for me).